# Php XML remove the parent node which has child nodes in existing file

Tags: php, xml, dom, nodes

> I'm trying to remove the parentnode itself from existing xml file

**XMLfile1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss>
  <channel>
    <title>Main Website</title>
    <link>siteurl</link>
    <item>
      <item_type>Product</item_type>
      <title>abcd</title>
      <sku>TESTsku</sku>
      <id>919031</id>
      <short_description><![CDATA[]]></short_description>
      <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
      <link>siteurl</link>
      <availability>Out of Stock</availability>
      <price>21.81 CAD</price>
      <sale_price>21.81 CAD</sale_price>
      <categories>
        <category/>
      </categories>
      <attributes>
   </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

**Expected XMLfile1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <rss>
      <channel>
        <title>Main Website</title>
        <link>siteurl</link>
      </channel>
    </rss>
```

I want to remove the `item` node if the file exists.

**What I have tried,**

```
$xmlBase = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss>
<channel>
        <title>Main Website</title>
        <link>siteurl</link>
</channel>
</rss>
XML;

$status = 1;
if ($status == 1) {
    $entitiesXML = new \SimpleXMLElement('XMLfile1.xml');
} else {
    $entitiesXML = new \SimpleXMLElement($xmlBase);
}
$fileExist = 'XMLfile1.xml';
if (file_exists($fileExist)) {
    $doc1 = new \DOMDocument('1.0');
    $doc1->loadXML($entitiesXML->asXML());
    $elements = $doc1->getElementsByTagName('channel');
    // $root = $doc1->firstChild;
    $nodes_to_insert = array();
    $nodes_to_remove = array();
    foreach($elements->childNodes as $item) {
        if($item->nodeName != "item") {
            continue;
        }
        $nodes_to_remove[] = $item;
    }
    foreach($nodes_to_remove as $node) {
        $elements->removeChild($node);
    }
    $doc1->saveXML();
}
```

I have tried bunch of other solutions with `DOMXpath` but not removing the `item` element.

Comment: Why not to use XSLT for the task?

Comment: I'm using the same codes( DOMDocument , SimpleXMLElement) for generating and updating the XML file so never heard of  XSLT, also this is simple xml data so, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: XSLT is a native API for XML transformations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just realized that Instead of removing the parent node I can set it as `$entitiesXML = new \SimpleXMLElement($xmlBase);`

which will set the XML file as the result I wanted.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <rss>
      <channel>
        <title>Main Website</title>
        <link>siteurl</link>
      </channel>
    </rss>
```

**My changes**

```
$xmlBase = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss>
<channel>
        <title>Main Website</title>
        <link>siteurl</link>
</channel>
</rss>
XML;

$status = 1;
if ($status == 1) {
    $entitiesXML = new \SimpleXMLElement($xmlBase);
} else {
    $entitiesXML = new \SimpleXMLElement($xmlBase);
}
if (file_exists($fileExist)) {
    $dom = new \DOMDocument('1.0');
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $dom->loadXML($entitiesXML->asXML(), LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);
    $dom->saveXML();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is XSLT based solution.

It is using a so called *Identity Transform* pattern.

[XSLT in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtoxml.php)

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss>
    <channel>
        <title>Main Website</title>
        <link>siteurl</link>
        <item>
            <item_type>Product</item_type>
            <title>abcd</title>
            <sku>T-B-B220-TB</sku>
            <id>919031</id>
            <short_description><![CDATA[]]></short_description>
            <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
            <link>siteurl</link>
            <availability>Out of Stock</availability>
            <price>21.81 CAD</price>
            <sale_price>21.81 CAD</sale_price>
            <categories>
                <category/>
            </categories>
            <attributes/>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity Transform pattern-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--remove item element-->
    <xsl:template match="item"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<rss>
  <channel>
    <title>Main Website</title>
    <link>siteurl</link>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

**PHP**

```
$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->importStylesheet($xsl);
$newXml = $proc->transformToXML($xml);
echo $newXml;
```